# MOTODEV Studio issue with SDK Install

Tags: android, sdk, installation, motodev-studio

I have previous Java programming experience and also Java Training from college, so I am looking to do some Java app development with Android. To that end I downloaded and installed MOTODEV studio from Motorola, which is partly based on Eclipse.

However it seemed to only have an SDK for Android 4 by default, I need the Android SDK for Android 2.3, but that is not installed, I have read that the way to install SDK packages is to open the SDK manager and there should be an option to download and install Android SDK's, but I do not see where that can be done.

Can someone provide some guidance in how to install SDK packages using MOTODEV Studio?

Thanks.

Comment: you can search for the SDK manager on windows, I suggest to run it as admin, there you can install any sdk packages you need

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Android SDK Manager

Wait for the list to load -> Select what you need -> Press "Install x packages"